# Invariant measures of the doubling map on the closed interval

Tags: measure-theory, ergodic-theory, invariance

Consider the doubling map $g\colon [0,1]\to [0,1]$ given by $g(x)=2x \, {\rm mod}\; 1$. It is clearly discontinuous at 1/2. However, its counterpart $G$ on the circle $G(e^{2\pi i \theta}) = e^{4\pi i \theta}$ ($\theta\in [0,1)$) is continuous therefore $G$ has many invariant measures.

Very often it is claimed in ergodic theory books that one may remove discontinuity of $g$ by passing to the circle (by identifying the end-points of $[0,1]$). It is however not clear to me whether this operation affects the $g$-invariant measures or not.

> Is there a one-to-one correspondence between $g$-invariant measures on $[0,1]$ and $G$-invariant ones on the circle?

It seems to me that this could be done if we took into account only those $g$-invariant measures whose probability distribution functions vanish at 0. Do I get this right?

Layman's explanation concerning passing from the interval to the circle in the case of the doubling map would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is quite small and can at most affect measures that assign masses to $0$ and/or $1$.

If you define $g(x) = \lfloor 2x \rfloor$, then $g$ is a map from $[0,1]$ to $[0,1)$. Any invariant measure must assign zero measure to $\{1\}$ and the Borel-sigma algebra of $[0,1)$ is isomorphic (for any Borel measure) to $S^1={\Bbb R}/{\Bbb Z}$. So in this case you may uniquely identify measures in the two cases.

If, however, you define e.g. $g(x)=2x$ for $x\in [0,0.5]$ and $g(x)=2x-1$ for $x\in (0.5]$ then you do actually have two invariant distinct dirac masses at $0$ and $1$. You have a similar scenario for other variations of defining the map at the end-points.

But the difference will be minor. In particular,
if you consider a measure that does not assign mass to 0 or 1 then from a measure point of view there is no difference between this system and the circle doubling map.